# Make ubuntu Server Accesible to the Internet

Tags: ubuntu, web-server, ubuntu-9.04

i just installed the latest version of ubuntu server, php, apache, shorewall and mysql.

the problem is that i cant access the website from other computers. i read that to fix that i need to change the DMZ or Port Forwarding. Im not sure how to do that. which document to change or what.

Comment: Also the problem is that i live on an apartment complex that the internet is included. i just plug the ethernet cable to the wall and i register on a time warner "HiSpeedUp" page and then i get the internet working. so i dont know how to check the router information or anything.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good reason to use one of the many web hosting services. Because unless you can get a port forwarded to your IP address there is no way for a public host to address your server. I don't know how the "Time Warner HiSpeedUp" system works, but I doubt that you will be provided with a public IP address that is not behind a firewall.

Comment: Sounds like on that sort of a system it's never, ever, ever going to happen.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to reconfigure your router to forward all requests (for port 80 or whatever you set it up to) to your web server.  How to configure the router depends on the router itself (they're all different).  Then you might need to open any necessary ports on the server firewall (if any).